# FB Fan-gate landing page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

I have done a lot of HW and found some code to make a fan gate landing page in facebook but I cant seem to get it working.  I am using google cloud storage so I can have a secure URL

I have a PHP file that references two HTML files and each of those references a CSS file.  Since they are all in the same directory (bucket) when referencing everything I simply put the file name and extension.  Based on my limited knowledge I think this should work and isn't the issue, let me know if I am wrong

I have found this bit of code and edited it to suit my needs:
I have it saved in this location:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/changed-to-protect-appsecret/facebook.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <?php
    require 'facebook.php';
    $app_id = "148002285301879";
    $app_secret = "myappsecret";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
     ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
    $page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
    $country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
    $locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

    // If a fan is on your page
    if ($like_status == 1) {
    $a = file_get_contents("fan.html");
    echo ($a);
    } else {
    // If a non-fan is on your page
    $a = file_get_contents("nofan.html");
    echo ($a);
    }

    ?>
```

Everything above is exactly as it is except the app secret.

I then uploaded HTML files to the same bucket and named them nonfan.html and fan.html as well as a file named fb.css and various images to be used.

On my Facebook app I don't know what to put for:

Canvas URL, Secrue Canvas URL, or Page Tab URL, Secure Page Tab URL.

For both of those I used one of the following depending on weather or not it was secure.

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/changed-to-protect-appsecret/facebook.php?

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/changed-to-protect-appsecret/facebook.php?

I added the "?" to the end because Facebook said I need it.  I also just changed the Http to Https, not sure if that is correct.

Here is where the landing page is:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Social-Media-Managers-Inc/120283264707317?sk=app_148002285301879

It is basically blank and I don't know what to do from here to figure out where the issue is.

Also not sure if the problem is with how I set up the facebook app or the PHP file not working properly or that the HTLM files are not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

"Also not sure if the problem is with how I set up the facebook app or the PHP file not working properly or that the HTLM files are not being loaded."

I've seen where the canvas was blank.  If you look at the HTML returned from facebook for your facebook page load, you will see an iframe that has no url specified to load.  I would be sure to doublecheck your app's settings one more time to ensure everything is good.

Comment: THanks for the reply DMCS.  I don't really know what I'd check for any suggestions, everything is as I put it.  Would a screen shot help??